# How to pass items in a list into xpath to download files from a web site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This code, below, is almost working, thanks totally to Jason Cook!  However, when I loop through items in a list, the second item always throws an error.  The first items works, but the second does not.  Here is the error message.

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='DatesDropDownList']/option[text()='UBPR Ratio -- Single Period']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

It seems like something needs to be reset, I guess.  The error mentioned above seems to come from this line of code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path+"/option[text()='"+select+"']").click()
```

Or, perhaps this line of code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path+"/option[text()='"+dates[j].text+"']").click()
```

Here is all the code.

```
    # browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe")
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time
    
    # using Google Chrome, can use the browser of your choice
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe')
    
    url = 'https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx'
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Wait for available products to load, and then select value.
    path = "//select[@id='ListBox1']"
    products = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, path)
        )
    )
    
    list = ['Call Reports -- Single Period',
            'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods',
            'UBPR Ratio -- Single Period']
      
    # Using for loop
    for item in list:
        select = item
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(path+"/option[text()='"+select+"']").click()
        
        time.sleep(2) # seconds
        
        #nWait for years to load. Get a list of the years. Select one of these as an example.
        path = "//select[@id='DatesDropDownList']"
        dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, path)
            )
        )
        
        time.sleep(2) # seconds
        
        for j in range(0, 5):
            dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path+'/option')
            
            # an example, you can loop through dates
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(path+"/option[text()='"+dates[j].text+"']").click()
            
            submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id("Download_0")
            submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Are you still on the right page, after executing the find elements?

Comment: I never moved off the initial page. I just tried to select different items in 'ListBox1' and 'DatesDropDownList'.

Comment: I feel like something needs to be refreshed, or switched, perhaps, but I don't know what that thing is.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML for one of the select option.

Comment: I think the whole thing is too long to post here, but essentially, it's like this:

<select size="6" name="ctl00$MainContentHolder$ListBox1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContentHolder$ListBox1\',\'\')', 0)" id="ListBox1" class="valuelabelN">
  <option value="PerformanceReportingSeriesFourPeriods">UBPR Ratio -- Four Periods</option>
  <option value="PerformanceReportingSeriesRank">UBPR Rank -- Four Periods</option>
  <option value="PerformanceReportingSeriesStats">UBPR Stats -- Four Periods</option>
</select>

Comment: And...the dates are setup like this:

<select name="ctl00$MainContentHolder$DatesDropDownList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContentHolder$DatesDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)" id="DatesDropDownList" class="valuelabel">
  <option selected="selected" value="124">09/30/2020</option>
  <option value="122">06/30/2020</option>
  <option value="121">03/31/2020</option>
  <option value="120">12/31/2019</option>
  <option value="119">09/30/2019</option>
  <option value="116">06/30/2019</option>
...
</select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`.
Use selenium `select` method to select the item

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx')
listproduct = ['Call Reports -- Single Period',
            'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods',
            'UBPR Ratio -- Single Period']

for product in listproduct:
    Weblistbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ListBox1")))
    select=Select(Weblistbox)
    select.select_by_visible_text(product)
    print("Product {} is selected".format(product))

    for year in range(0,5):
        datedropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DatesDropDownList")))
        select = Select(datedropdown)
        select.select_by_index(year)
        datedropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DatesDropDownList")))
        select = Select(datedropdown)
        print("DateOrYear {} is selected".format(select.first_selected_option.text))
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'Download_0'))).click()

    print("================================")
```

Your console output will be like this.

```
Product Call Reports -- Single Period is selected
DateOrYear 09/30/2020 is selected
DateOrYear 06/30/2020 is selected
DateOrYear 03/31/2020 is selected
DateOrYear 12/31/2019 is selected
DateOrYear 09/30/2019 is selected
================================
Product Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods is selected
DateOrYear 2020 is selected
DateOrYear 2019 is selected
DateOrYear 2018 is selected
DateOrYear 2017 is selected
DateOrYear 2016 is selected
================================
Product UBPR Ratio -- Single Period is selected
DateOrYear 09/30/2020 is selected
DateOrYear 06/30/2020 is selected
DateOrYear 03/31/2020 is selected
DateOrYear 12/31/2019 is selected
DateOrYear 09/30/2019 is selected
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much!!